# converting single PHP mySQL update into mass MySQL update

Tags: mysql, curl, foreach

Ok so thank you for the feedback until now, with it I have got to the following point:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "madtags";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id from users");
$userinfo = array();

while ($row_user = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    $userinfo[] = $row_user;

foreach ($userinfo as $user) {

$url = "http://www.pdga.com/player/".$user['id'];
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$class = 'current-rating';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div) {
    preg_match('/Current Rating:\s+(\d+)/', $div->nodeValue, $results);
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET rating=$results[1] WHERE id=id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully <br>";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record <br> " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


}

?>
```

By changing the "where" command on row 45 "$sql = "UPDATE users SET rating=$results[1] WHERE id=id";", i can get it to run properly (this is a test array of 6 rows)

```
Record updated successfully 
Error updating record 
Error updating record 
Error updating record 
Error updating record 
Error updating record
```

But I guess I am defining something wrong as it is not able to update the record after the first run.

Ideas?

***original post***

I am creating a competition website, parallel to a rating system used by a worldwide website. So basically I have created the code below to call for a rating from the website.

Since creating this, the member base has ballooned greatly. So creating this code individually for each member is not useful anymore. So I would need to develop this to basically run for each row in my MySQL table (this code is run every 2 weeks approx.)

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "madtags";
$url = "http://www.pdga.com/player/***ID***";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$class = 'current-rating';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div) {
    preg_match('/Current Rating:\s+(\d+)/', $div->nodeValue, $results);
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE users SET rating=$results[1] WHERE id=***ID***";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So basically variable for each individual line are the parts marked ***ID*** ($url and $sql update).

Further, the table currently has 4 columns >> id, name, tag, rating

Thanks a bunch ahead of time.

Comment: if the rating for each user is different, then you have to do a separate update SQL statement for each. There's not really any way round it. You can't do a bulk UPDATE if the values you want to set are different in each row, it wouldn't make sense. UPDATE works on sets of rows, so if you want to change them all the same way you can, but not if each change is different. Unless that's not what you're asking?

Comment: uhh so. The rating for each individual is different, and they are all found on individual website addresses (as each individual at the PDGA website has a unique ID)

I understand that they need to be run separately, was just wondering if there is a smart way to do that rather then having to individually create such a php file for each member.

Comment: why would you have to create a new file for each member??  Presumably you have got required `ID` variable in your users table in the database? If so then just retrieve all your users details from the database into an array, loop through them one by one and run your existing code for each one, passing the specific user details each time (you could put this code into a function so you can call it repeatedly with different parameters).

Comment: Myes you have the idea of what I'm looking for. Honestly this is quite far over my head as it took me a while to even get where I am, and now with the fast increasing member count I just haven't had time to study enough php to streamline this myself. I will look into the loading table into an array, sounds like a good solution. uhh stupid question I am sure but how would you go about inserting a value into a url (see $url = "http://www.pdga.com/player/***ID***";)

Comment: it's just string concatention. Assuming you have the ID in a variable, then something like `$url = "http://pdga.com/player/".$id;`

Comment: and for the other part, find some examples of how to do a SELECT query and use mysqli to run the query and retrieve the data into an array. And then how to use a foreach loop to run through them. Each bit is fairly straightforward PHP and simple in itself. I can write you an example answer if you're still stuck.

Comment: Alright, i went ahead with some of your feedback. Opinions/solutions to that mess?

Comment: `WHERE id=id` is self-referencing. So it will update all the rows because id (in the DB) always equals id (in the DB, same variable). You need to concatenate your PHP id variable into the string: `WHERE id =".$user['id'];` should do it.

Comment: Ah Yeah I was trying to figure out the syntax when I posted this so accidentally posted one without any :D Anyway thank you very much sir, works now.